# Match number value from JSON-LD with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get a number value from JSON-LD with regex. If i match a quoted value, like `"price": "0.00"` my regex works: `"price": "(.*?)"`.
But if the value is just a number, like `"ratingValue": 5`, my regex stops working.

What should be the regex to match the number in examples liek `"ratingValue": 5`? I tried `"ratingValue": (.*?)`, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Use `"ratingValue": *"?([0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
"(?:ratingValue|price)": *"?([0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ggikzq/1). *Details*:

- `"` - a double quote
- `(?:ratingValue|price)` - either of the two alternative strings
- `":` - a `":` string
- `*"?` - zero or more spaces followed with an optional `"` char
- `([0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a dot and one or more digits.